# Copy workbook one by one into archive folder

Tags: vba, excel

I used the below code which perfectly does its job of picking up all the files and moving them into Archive folder. However, I am looking for files to be picked up one by one get the date into Target workbook and move it to archive folder and this process goes on till the last workbook. I have used the below code to copy the data and have called the Sub routine to perform the Archive.
But it moves all the file at once into Archive folder in the first iteration.

```
Sub Test()
    Dim xWb As Workbook
    Dim xToBook As Workbook
    Dim xStrPath As String
    Dim xFileDialog As FileDialog
    Dim xFile As String
    Dim xFiles As New Collection
    Dim I As Long
    Set xFileDialog = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
    xFileDialog.AllowMultiSelect = False
    xFileDialog.Title = "Select a folder [Kutools for Excel]"
    If xFileDialog.Show = -1 Then
        xStrPath = xFileDialog.SelectedItems(1)
    End If
    If xStrPath = "" Then Exit Sub
    If Right(xStrPath, 1) <> "\" Then xStrPath = xStrPath & "\"
    xFile = Dir(xStrPath & "*.xlsx")
    If xFile = "" Then
        MsgBox "No files found", vbInformation, "Kutools for Excel"
        Exit Sub
    End If
    Do While xFile <> ""
        xFiles.Add xFile, xFile
        xFile = Dir()
    Loop
    Set xToBook = ThisWorkbook
    If xFiles.Count > 0 Then
        For I = 1 To xFiles.Count
            Set xWb = Workbooks.Open(xStrPath & xFiles.Item(I))
            xWb.Worksheets(1).Copy after:=xToBook.Sheets(xToBook.Sheets.Count)
            On Error Resume Next
            ActiveSheet.Name = xWb.Name
            On Error GoTo 0
            xWb.Close False
            '**Call MoveFiles_3**
        Next I
    End If
End Sub

Sub MoveFiles_3()
    Dim fso As Object, d As String, ext, x
    Dim srcPath As String, destPath As String, srcFile As String
    srcPath = "C:\Users\userfolder\Desktop\Test Macro\"
    destPath = "C:\Users\userfolder\Desktop\Archive Test\"
    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    ext = Array("*.xlsx")
    MsgBox Dir(srcPath)
    For Each x In ext
        d = Dir(srcPath & x)
        Do While d <> ""
            srcFile = srcPath & d
            fso.CopyFile srcFile, destPath & d
            Kill srcFile
        d = Dir
        Loop
    Next x
    MsgBox "done"
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Try below code.  I add two lines in your `Test` and `MoveFiles_3` is needless.

```
Sub Test()
    Dim xWb As Workbook
    Dim xToBook As Workbook
    Dim xStrPath As String
    Dim xFileDialog As FileDialog
    Dim xFile As String
    Dim xFiles As New Collection
    Dim I As Long
    Set xFileDialog = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
    xFileDialog.AllowMultiSelect = False
    xFileDialog.Title = "Select a folder [Kutools for Excel]"
    If xFileDialog.Show = -1 Then
        xStrPath = xFileDialog.SelectedItems(1)
    End If
    If xStrPath = "" Then Exit Sub
    If Right(xStrPath, 1) <> "\" Then xStrPath = xStrPath & "\"
    xFile = Dir(xStrPath & "*.xlsx")
    If xFile = "" Then
        MsgBox "No files found", vbInformation, "Kutools for Excel"
        Exit Sub
    End If
    Do While xFile <> ""
        xFiles.Add xFile, xFile
        xFile = Dir()
    Loop
    Set xToBook = ThisWorkbook
    If xFiles.Count > 0 Then
        For I = 1 To xFiles.Count
            Set xWb = Workbooks.Open(xStrPath & xFiles.Item(I))
            xWb.Worksheets(1).Copy after:=xToBook.Sheets(xToBook.Sheets.Count)
            On Error Resume Next
            ActiveSheet.Name = xWb.Name
            On Error GoTo 0
            xWb.Close False

            Name xStrPath & xFiles.Item(I) As "C:\Users\userfolder\Desktop\Archive Test\" & xFiles.Item(I) ' new added'
            Kill xStrPath & xFiles.Item(I) ' new added'
        Next I
    End If
End Sub
```